# Problemas ao salvar banco de dados XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

Estou com muito problema com meu `xampp`, tem algum tempo que venho tentando adicionar qualquer coisa no banco de dados `mysql` porém não tenho êxito em minhas tentativas.

No `error.log` do PHP está descrito as seguintes linhas:

> [Sat Feb 13 01:31:07.052501 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2604:tid 468] AH00455: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Sat Feb 13 01:31:07.052501 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2604:tid 468] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Dec  9 2015 10:17:39
>
> [Sat Feb 13 01:31:07.052501 2016] [core:notice] [pid 2604:tid 468] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
>
> [Sat Feb 13 01:31:07.064486 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2604:tid 468] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6052
>
> [Sat Feb 13 01:31:09.051887 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 6052:tid 116] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>
> [Sat Feb 13 01:31:09.457471 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 6052:tid 116] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>
> [Sat Feb 13 01:31:09.562545 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6052:tid 116] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

Estou fazendo um `insert` simples como a seguir:

```
try {
    $campos = array();
    $campos[':TXT_NOMEX_BANNE'] = $targetFile;
    $campos[':pesso'] = '1'; //$suc->$COD_IDENT_USUAR();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_banner (`TXT_NOMEX_BANNE`, `COD_ULTIM_ATUAL`, `DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL`) VALUES (:TXT_NOMEX_BANNE, :pesso, now())";
    $conexao = new ConexaoDatabase();
    $conexao->save($sql, $campos);

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
} catch (Exception $e) {

    die('ERRO AO ATUALIZAR BANCO DE DADOS');
    error_log($e->getMessage());
}
```

Minhas estrutura de pasta está a seguinte:

```
|includes
|--conexao.php
|--suc_validacao.php
|paginas
|--upload.php
```

E estou dando um include da seguinte maneira:

```
include '../includes/suc_validacao.php';
include '../includes/conexao.php';
```

Na `conexao.php` tenho uma função `save`, e ela chama outra função. Ambas descrita abaixo:

```
   public function save($sql, array $data) {

        $con = self::getConnection();

        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);

        $this->execute($stmt, $data);

        if ($stmt->rowCount()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function execute(PDOStatement $stmt, array $data = null) {
        try {
            if (isset($data)) {
                $stmt->execute($data);
            } else {
                $stmt->execute();
            }
            return true;
        } catch (PDOException $exc) {
            if (isset($_SESSION['suc'])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Se tiver mais alguma coisa para adicionar, porém tentei fazer muitas coisas, entre elas reinstalar o `xampp`, refazer o `insert`, entre outras. Nenhuma deu certo, ja procurei na internet algo sobre o erro, porém também não encontrei nada sobre.

Adoraria a ajuda para solucionar este problema.

Comment: esse error.log não apareceu nada que tem haver com o mysql... é erro de código da sua aplicação mesmo...

Comment: Você tem um try catch no método execute silenciando a exception do PDO. Experimente retira-lo e ver qual mensagem de erro o PHP retorna.

Comment: @jefersondaniel deu este erro [Sat Feb 13 01:32:23.744686 2016] [negotiation:error] [pid 6052:tid 1816] [client ::1:56891] AH00690: no acceptable variant: C:/xampp/apache/error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var, referer: http://localhost:8080/take_web/admin/paginas/banner.php
[Sat Feb 13 09:38:59.366448 2016] [negotiation:error] [pid 6052:tid 1816] [client ::1:58029] AH00690: no acceptable variant: C:/xampp/apache/error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var, referer: http://localhost:8080/take_web/admin/paginas/banner.php